# Loops around 0 of polynomial restricted to the unit circle

Tags: polynomials, complex-numbers

Given a polynomial with coefficients in C, consider the image of the polynomial restricted to the unit circle (That is plugging in only things with absolute value one). How many loops around 0 can this image do? I'm thinking that at most the degree of the polynomial but I haven't been able to come up with a reason.

Comment: Thinking about this more, I'm not so sure that the "restriction to the unit circle" makes sense - if I give you a function $f(z) = 10z^3 + 2z$, does this mean that you will send only inputs that yield an output on the unit circle, or do you take all inputs and "normalize" them to get points on the unit circle?

Comment: @SiddharthBhat It means that I only plug things in from the unit circle

Comment: so the only inputs you give are on the unit circle, and you're interested in how the output behaves, in terms of looping?

Comment: Yes, since I only want the bound, it'd be enough to show that it has at most n intersections with the real axis (I assume this is true).

Comment: Look at the polynomial $z$. It has two intersections with the real line.

Comment: @SoumyaSinha sorry I meant nonnegative real axis, good catch.

Comment: @Semiclassical Thanks I guess that does answer, is there something more elementary though?

Comment: I doubt it. But I think the characterization is pretty simple: The winding number of $f(C_r)$ around 0 is the same as the number of zeros of $f(x)$ which lie within $C_r$.